# How to show multiple column in Crystal report

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm building a report with Crystal report 13.0.18. I have this problem. In my report, I have a section with a list of pairs of values, like:

```
Tom    | 18
Jerry  | 21
Joy    | 15
Frank  | 16
Lisa   | 18
```

This section has a fixed height. If a number of values are greater then the height, I would have another column on the right.

```
Tom    | 18      Frank | 16
Jerry  | 21      Lisa  | 18
Joy    | 15
```

I'm trying to set a property multiple columns, in the Expert Section of the detail section, but the result is this:

```
Tom  | 18       Jerry  | 21
Joy  | 15       Frank  | 16
Lisa | 18
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Section Expert when you check the property to Format with Multiple Columns you should see a new tab appear at the top called Layout.  If you navigate to the Layout tab you will find a group of controls labeled "Printing Direction:".  In this group of controls you can choose between "Across then Down" and "Down then Across".

Going by the sample output you provided, it looks like you are using "Across then Down" when you want it to be "Down then Across".

It also looks like you may want to increase the Vertical Gap Between Details to create more space between your columns.  This control is also found on the Layout tab.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but if I use the property  "Down then Across" , Crystal report  writes the list in sequence , like my first example, by increasing the section's size. It dosn't go to the next column. The different space between the columns isn't an important  feature.

Comment: Do you have the Can Grow property enabled perhaps?  When using Down then Across for a column layout with the Can Grow enable I would expect the behavior you describe.  Unfortunately, the Can Grow will only allow vertical growth, so if you have a fixed height, it should be disabled.

Comment: @gaby - It may also be helpful if you could provide a more specific explanation of the problem you are having with your output.  When I first answered your question I was under the impression the problem was the order your list items were printing in the output.  I did notice the number for Joy changed in your sample output, but I had dismissed that as a typo from a copy and paste.  At this point I'm not clear as to exactly what your problem is though.

Comment: Thank you so much! I solved my problem with your solution!